# Warn Users when application crashes or exited and Post crashlog- iPhone

Tags: iphone

Hii People,

i want to set up a default exception handler for all application exceptions or crashed ,

The goal is to display a alertview to display the crash log and warn users that application is unstable to continue and exit with some time interval and collect those crash logs and post to client server for error handling.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Don't display the crash log to the end user, it's useless.

Comment: @Benj : Yes,sure but i ll display a alert to notify that app going to exit and post clarsh log to client server url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just integrated this open source framework into my application: [QuincyKit](https://github.com/TheRealKerni/QuincyKit).

If your app crashes, the next time it is started it gives the user the opportunity to send the crash report to a server.

Comment: Thanks, i want to make sure that whether apple will recognize this framework or Not wwhile app submission.

Comment: I've submitted three apps with this code (actually an older version with a different name) and Apple have published them without any problems.

Comment: Thanks for the comment & although i using these for Dev but now i should consider to add them to store also with my apps:) -